# Remove drop shadow in leaveEvent

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to remove the drop shadow effect in leaveEvent. Here's my code:

```py
class GroupBox(QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, shadow=True):
        super(GroupBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self.isShadow = shadow

        if self.isShadow == True:
            self.shadow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect()
        elif self.isShadow == False:
            self.shadow = None

       

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        if self.shadow != None:  
            self.shadow.setBlurRadius(10)
            self.shadow.setOffset(0, 0) 
            self.setGraphicsEffect(self.shadow)


    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.shadow = None
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove the QGraphicsEffect then you must pass None to the setGraphicsEffect method but the side effect is that the QGraphicsEffect will be removed so you have to re-create the QGraphicsEffect:

```py
class GroupBox(QGroupBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, shadow=True):
        super(GroupBox, self).__init__(parent)
        self._is_shadow = shadow

    @property
    def is_shadow(self):
        return self._is_shadow

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        if self.is_shadow:
            shadow_effect = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(
                blurRadius=10, offset=QPointF(0, 0)
            )
            self.setGraphicsEffect(shadow_effect)

    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        if self.is_shadow:
            self.setGraphicsEffect(None)
```